# Having trouble with Parse query in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using a Parse query to retrieve a profil pic and a user name, and then adding to a list, but it seems that's not working the list is always Empty.

Why instructions inside the done function works, and when I use them out of the done function it doesn't work

here is my code :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("test");
query2.whereEqualTo("user", "user1");
query2.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (object == null) {

        } else {
            image = (ParseFile) Messages.get("Profil"); 
            String user = object.get("name").toString();
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not able to retrieve the user name, it's showing null

Comment: do you have a class in parse called "test" ?

Comment: what does the exception    say ?

Comment: The call is asynchronous meaning that your program will not wait for your query to finish before moving onto the next line of code. Any processing of the data retrieved by the query needs to be done within side the callback function (done).